How to Add a Custom Virtual Printer in the Default Print Dialog to Post Files to a Webserver?
I am looking to develop a virtual printer that integrates with Windows applications via the default print dialog so a user can print webpages or files and have them be sent to our server. Essentially the goal for this virtual printer is to capture documents and directly post them as files to a predefined web server URL, rather than just sending print jobs to a physical or network printer.
I have not yet started coding this feature and am seeking advice on appropriate technologies and methods for implementing such a system in a Windows environment. Specifically, I need guidance on:

Creating a virtual printer that appears in the standard Windows print
dialog.
Capturing the print job data from applications.
Converting this data into a standard file format (e.g., PDF).
Sending these files to a web server via HTTP POST requests.

Could anyone provide insights or examples on how to set up this virtual printer functionality, particularly focusing on capturing and redirecting print jobs to a web server? Any recommended libraries or frameworks that could facilitate this process would also be greatly appreciated.

What is the actual requirement? Because networked printers already work in the way you describe. Almost all use IPP - the Internet Printing Protocol and soon this will be the only way to print remotely. Before that Windows offered printing web services through the WS-Print web service standard

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
